# How do I prove this trig identity without geometry?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need to prove this:

$$\cos(x) = \frac{1-\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}$$

using only $\sin(a-b)$ and $\cos(a-b)$ formulas wich I already proved. I also proven this:

$$\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$$
$$\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$$
$$\cos(2x) = \cos^2x -\sin^2(x)$$
$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
and the $\sin(a+b)$ and $\cos(a+b)$ formulas. Do I need something more so I can prove this identity? Could you guys give me some help?

Comment: I recommend setting $x=2y$ and substituting the variable $y$ in for $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$$  dividing the numerator & the denominator by $\cos^2x$

---

Dividing the numerator & the denominator by $\cos^2x$ 
$$\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{\sec^2x}=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$$

Comment: why did you divide by $cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)$?

Comment: Because that’s equal to $1$.